# MVC 4 Passing Data To Partial View - Format

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble getting my head around partial views in MVC4. I currently have a User Profile page and I want to have a partial view displaying each record from another table that contains their UserID.

This is the HTML helper I'm using to call my function in the controller .

```
   @Html.Action("DisplayArticles", "Articles")
```

This is the method I call in my Article controller to display a user's articles.

```
   [HttpGet]
   [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DisplayArticles()
         {
           int id = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
           var articleList = new List<Article>();

           //Article articles = (from j in db.Article
           //         where j.UserID == id
           //         select j).ToList();

           //articleList.AddRange(articles);
           foreach (Article i in db.Article)
           {
               if (i.UserID == id)
               {
                   articleList.Add(i);
               }
           }


           return PartialView("_DisplayWritersArticle", articleList);
         }
```

My partial view _DisplayWriterArticle simply uses HTML helpers to display the data.

```
@model Writegeist.Models.Article

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

My problem is the way that I'm passing my list into the view, It isn't getting recognised and I'm getting the error

```
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Writegeist.Models.Article]', but
> this dictionary requires a model item of type
> 'Writegeist.Models.Article'.
```

If I change

```
return PartialView("_DisplayWritersArticle", articleList);
```

to

```
return PartialView("_DisplayWritersArticle", new Writegeist.Models.Article());
```

I assume the articleList isn't in the right format. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: You don't have the code for your partial _DisplayWritersArticle posted, but it looks like it has it's model set as a single Writegeist.Models.Article. You're sending it a List of Articles, which it does not know how to deal with.  Post your Partial View code.

Comment: I thought I didn't need it because it was so simple. I included it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Partial View is expecting a single Article, you're giving it a list of them.

Change the model to a list of Articles:

```
@model List<Writegeist.Models.Article>
```

Then you have to loop through the list to display them all:

```
<table>
@foreach(Article article in Model) {
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => article.UserID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => article.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => article.Type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(a => article.Content)
        </th>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: That was the exact same answer I provided heh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as I see it that you are passing a List but you are telling the view it is a just an Article.

Change your

```
@model Writegeist.Models.Article to @model List<Writegeist.Models.Article>
```

Then you'll want to iterate over that list to get the data you are expecting.

Comment: I've done that but I get an error saying that: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Writegeist.Models.Article>' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' 

It is definatly declared in my model class though

Comment: But you're trying to access the `UserID` of the _List_ of Articles, not an individual `Article`, and it doesn't have a property of `UserID`.  You have to iterate through the list and then try to access the `UserID` of each _individual_ member of the List.